# Unity объект зависает в воздухе

Tags: unity3d-editor

Делаю 2д платформер
Когда мой персонаж подпрыгивает и я двигаюсь вправо и касаюсь другого объекта то мой персонаж зависает в воздухе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а когда отпускаю кнопку вправо то он падает вниз
А персонажи есть RigidBody2D Box Collider2D

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Расскажите подробнее о своей проблеме, дайте код.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема состоит в физике.

Подправьте немного `RigidBody`, увеличьте массу, может поможет

Answer (score 0):

Я добавил скрипт что когда я прикасаюсь к стене и не нахожусь на земле то опускаюсь вниз

`if(isGravity && IsGrounded() == false)

{

rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, -5, 0);

}

else {isGravity = false;}
`

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: Нет , єто ответ но я почемуто не могу отметить как ответ ;0